# Using <b> in fckeditor

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

i want to print some default string value in bold but i am using   tag but it is not rendered as bold rather it is showing it is printing the same   etc

```
var defaultFCKValue = '----Original Message---- \n';
            defaultFCKValue += '<b>From:</b> ' + from + '\n';
            defaultFCKValue += '<b>Sent:</b> ' + date + '\n';
            defaultFCKValue += $('div.popupContent div div.message').html();
            var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("<%=FCKeditorSelfDocument.ClientID %>");
            var oDOM = oEditor.EditorDocument;
            oDOM.body.innerText = defaultFCKValue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `<b>` tags are being escaped/encoded and are being rendered as `&lt;b&gt;`

You might want to try using

```
oEditor.setHtml(defaultFCKValue)
```

See the [js docmentation for fckeditor](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API).

Answer (score 0):

Try `<strong>` rather than `<b>`, as `<b>` tags have been depreciated in most doctypes. It may not directly solve your problem, but it is at least good practice.